# How to split one column to three column in excel?

Tags: excel

How do i split the first picture(whole address) into second picture(address, city, state, zipcode). I have more than thousand data, so kindly suggest me the easy method?

All the whole address is formatted as **729 quail creek drive, frisco tx 75034**

I need to split Address as **729 quail creek drive**, City as **frisco**, State as **tx** and zipcode as **75034**.

[image: Whole Address]

[image: Split Address, city, state, zipcode]
Thanks

Comment: Answer: With great difficulty, because Excel does not support regex matching.  I vote for not doing this task in Excel.

Comment: It will depend on how your data is formatted. Please provide some examples and what you have tried

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've handled this in two examples below using either a `Split` method or a `RegEx` method

Answer (score 1):

If you know your data will always be of this format:

```
<address>, <city> <2-letter state> <5-digit zip code>
```

Then this is the easiest way I can think of:

Formula for `<address>`:

```
= LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1)
```

Formula for `<city>`:

```
= MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+2,LEN(A1)-FIND(",",A1)-10)
```

Formula for `<2-letter state>`:

```
= MID(A1,LEN(A1)-7,2)
```

Formula for `<5-digit zip code>`:

```
= RIGHT(A1,5)
```

See below example.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with `RegExp` but instead of figuring out the `RegExp` pattern I've used the `Split` function and a couple of arrays. I've assumed that the Address is before the comma.

```
Sub SplitAddress()
    Dim Addresses As Variant, results As Variant, tmp As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    ' Update for you range
    With Sheet1
        'Trick to get 1D array from range
        Addresses = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, "A")))
    End With

    ReDim results(1 To UBound(Addresses), 1 To 4)

    For i = 1 To UBound(results, 1)
        tmp = Split(Addresses(i), ",")
        results(i, 1) = Trim(tmp(0))

        tmp = Split(Trim(tmp(1)), " ")

        For j = LBound(tmp) To UBound(tmp)
            results(i, j + 2) = Trim(tmp(j))
        Next j
    Next i

    ' Update for your destination
    With Sheet1.Cells(2, "B")
        Range(.Offset(0, 0), .Offset(UBound(results, 1) - 1, UBound(results, 2) - 1)).Value2 = results
    End With
End Sub
```

***Updated with RegExp***

This method uses `RegExp` to split your strings

```
Sub splitAddressRegEx()
    Dim ReGex As Object
    Dim Addresses As Range
    Dim j As Long
    Dim c, m

    ' Update for your range
    With Sheet1
        Set Addresses = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, "A"))
    End With
    Set ReGex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With ReGex
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "(.+?(?=,))|(\w+)"
    End With

    For Each c In Addresses
        j = 1
        If ReGex.Test(c.Value2) Then
            For Each m In ReGex.Execute(c.Value2)
                ' Update for your output
                c.Offset(0, j).Value2 = m
                j = j + 1
            Next m
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```